# Query to single ElasticSearch node in cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, cluster-computing

We test an ElasticSearch cluster with 36 shards on 3 nodes, without replication. Is it possible to get results from just a single node, for testing purposes?

I didn't find any thing about it in [docs](http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html).

Comment: Can you explain your testing purpose with example?

Comment: In general, I want to determine if some nodes work slower then others. Alternatively it would be fine if ElasticSearch returned time that query took on each node, instead of overall time. But I didn't find the way to do it as well

Comment: @VirajParab for example if one of my 3 nodes fall down, I get 2/3 of results, which is expected. Can I do it without shutting down my node?

Comment: Not really but you can make call to specific shard on specific node, Or you can shutdown the node from the api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html , means not real node shutdown but sort for elasticsearch node shutdown.

Comment: @VirajParab thanks. Call to specific shards is the way we went eventually

Comment: But can you explain how you get the exact shard routing? like which algorithm you used?

Comment: I used this one: `?preference=_shards:1,4,7` ... Since I know which shards reside on which node, I can list them in the above form

Comment: Great ... so document will be in one of them .. Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `preference` parameter is what you need. Look at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html).